# Responsive image with magnific plugin

Tags: responsive-design

I am new there, new in responsive approach and would like a first impetus (?) handling source on http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

My first question: Which image is referenced in the html-body (large or thumbnail)?

If thumbnail - where is the large? 
Is it possible to load just an image great enough for th viewport and not larger?

Thanks in advance, 
 Karl

Answer (score 0):

In the website you linked to, both the thumbnail and the pop out use the same image.

It is possible to load images based on the viewport size using the `srcset` attribute on the img tag.

A simple example:

```
<img srcset="small.jpg 1x, large.jpg 2x"
   src="small.jpg"
   alt="Alt text" />
```

This provides a nice fallback for browsers that don't support the srcset attribute as well.

You can find a comprehensive usage guide [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/).

Comment: This is fine, Pavlin. I did not find such in a recently buyed expensive book about responsive design.

Comment: >
<img src="layout/bild/VomWald_rev1024.jpg" alt="default"
 srcset="layout/bild/VomWald_rev640.jpg 640w,
   layout/bild/VomWald_rev1024.jpg 1024w,
    layout/bild/VomWald_rev1024.jpg 2x"
sizes="(min-width: 36em) 92vw, 100vw" > 
  --- my new question: are the 1x and 2x images equal? I did this all to save bandwidth (for guests), to on my phone there comes the 2x version and takes just a third of the width, may be in better quality (retina).